# ejabberd stringprep error

Tags: ejabberd

I install ejabberd from source, it always gives error when I start :

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2013-01-05 09:35:58 ===
    application: ejabberd
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {badarg,
                         [{erlang,port_control,
                              [stringprep_port,2,"localhost"]},
                          {stringprep,control,2},
                          {jlib,nodeprep,1},
                          {ejabberd_config,normalize_hosts,2},
                          {ejabberd_config,add_hosts_to_option,2},
                          {lists,foldl,3},
                          {ejabberd_config,load_file,1},
                          {ejabberd_config,start,0}]}}}}
    type: temporary

=ERROR REPORT==== 2013-01-05 09:37:52 ===
Error in process <0.108.0> on node 'ejabberd@localhost' with exit value: {{case_clause,{error,{open_error,-13}}},[{ejabberd_app,init,0}]}


=INFO REPORT==== 2013-01-05 09:37:54 ===
    application: ejabberd
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {badarg,
                         [{erlang,port_control,
                              [stringprep_port,2,"localhost"]},
                          {stringprep,control,2},
                          {jlib,nodeprep,1},
                          {ejabberd_config,normalize_hosts,2},
                          {ejabberd_config,add_hosts_to_option,2},
                          {lists,foldl,3},
                          {ejabberd_config,load_file,1},
                          {ejabberd_config,start,0}]}}}}
    type: temporary
```

The Erlang version I have tried: r14b02 r14b04 r15b02 (I installed erlang by kerl tool)

The ejabberd version I have tries: 2.1.10/2.1.11/3.0.alpha5

The OS I have tried 64 bit OSX / 32 bit ubuntu